# Shopware : Impossible to extend through plugin user-detail

Tags: shopware

I have Shopware 6.5.3. I was trying to extend "sw-users-permissions-user-detail" like this :

```
import template from './sw-users-permissions-user-detail.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.override('sw-users-permissions-user-detail', {
    template
});
```

And file 'sw-users-permissions-user-detail.html.twig'

```
{% block sw_settings_user_detail %}
    {% parent %}
    {% block test %}
        <p>Blabla</p>
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

It's not working at all, and I don't know why.
Any help ?

*NB : It's working when I'm overriding other templates :*

```
Component.override('sw-dashboard-index', {
    template
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the original contents to the block, that you are overriding, you should use the 'parent' statement like this:

```
{{ parent() }}
```